# performSelector on c++ class method?

Tags: iphone, c++, performselector

Can I call performSelector on c++ class member function somehow?

I'm thinking of creating a dummy objc class that will receive performSelector call, and this dummy class calling the desired c++ member function.

But is there a better way?

(Reason I don't want to just call the method right away is because of threading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call an objective c message on a c++ class instance because of fundamental differences in the internals (look into objc_msgSend(), which requires the objective c run-time). You could look into function pointers, or [boost](http://www.boost.org/) C++ libraries like [bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html) or [function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/function.html). Alternatively, you could, as you say, make a wrapper which forwards obj c messages as c++ method calls.

Comment: boost bind/function can be used to performSelector on a specific thread?(main thread)

Comment: It's quite a large topic, boost::bind can work together with boost::thread http://blog.emptycrate.com/node/277. Alternatively, performSelectorOnThread type messages can be sent to the object, the C++ code will be executed on that thread.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to do this. I would create your Objective-C dummy receiver and call your C++ class from there. I've done the same thing in order to receive UI events in C++ classes.